# Printar resultado em DIV

Tags: php, mysql, div, algoritmo-de-busca

Como consigo colocar os resultado em cada div diferente.
Precisa exibir a imagem buscando de um diretório e um link que direcione para determinada página.

```
<?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "admin";
$senha = "";
$dbname = "uaicheibd";
//Criar a conexao
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

$pesquisar = $_POST['pesquisar'];
$result_clientes = "SELECT * FROM pesquisaclientes WHERE palavras_chave LIKE '%$pesquisar%' LIMIT 5";
$resultado_clientes = mysqli_query($conn, $result_clientes);


    echo '<div class="resultados">';
while($rows_clientes = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_clientes)){
    echo "Cliente: ".$rows_clientes['nome']."<br>";
    echo "Bairro: ".$rows_clientes['bairro']."<br>";
    echo "Categoria: ".$rows_clientes['categoria']."<br>";
    echo "Subcategoria: ".$rows_clientes['subcategoria']."<br>";
    echo "Link: ".$rows_clientes['link_cliente']."<br>";
    echo "Logo: ".$rows_clientes['logo']."<br>";
}
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Não basta fazer o `echo` da div dentro do seu `while`? Se não, então eu não entendi a dúvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O link você coloca em uma tag `<a>` onde o atributo `href` (e o texto, se quiser) será a informação vinda do banco:

```
echo "Link: <a href='".$rows_clientes['link_cliente']."'>".$rows_clientes['link_cliente']."</a><br>";
```

No caso da imagem, coloque numa tag `<img>` onde o atributo `src` será o caminho da imagem + a informação vinda do banco:

```
echo "Logo: <img src='caminho_do_diretorio/".$rows_clientes['logo']."'><br>";
```

Onde em `caminho_do_diretorio` você irá colocar o caminho da pasta, que pode ser uma subpasta, uma pasta anterior etc. Vai depender da estrutura de pastas ou da forma que irá buscar a pasta onde está a imagem.

Por exemplo, se estiver numa pasta `imagens` no mesmo diretório da página, irá fazer:

```
echo "Logo: <img src='imagens/".$rows_clientes['logo']."'><br>";
```

Ou você pode buscar de forma global, independentemente de onde está a página, usando `./`:

```
echo "Logo: <img src='./site/imagens/".$rows_clientes['logo']."'><br>";
```

No caso acima, irá buscar a imagem dentro da pasta `site/imagens` à partir da pasta raiz.

Comment: Perfeito Sam.
Muito obrigado.